# I want to count words in ms word file

Tags: php, html

I am using COM class of php for count the number of words in ms word file. It is running fine on my local. But when i run it on server than it gives the error.

Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/classics/public_html/filecount/index.php on line 33

Although i am not including COM class on local also and i have not this type of class i am just using it just like that:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file = $_FILES['docfile']['name'];
        $file = str_replace(" ","_",$file);
        $ranname = mt_rand(100,10000);

        //$file = file_get_contents($file);
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target ="uploads/";
        if(!is_dir($target))
        { 
        mkdir($target, 0755);
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['docfile']['tmp_name'],$target.$ranname.".docx");
        if($ext == "doc" || $ext == "docx"){
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word"); 

$word->Visible = 1; 


$word->Documents->Open("/filecount/".$target.$ranname.".docx");
$temp = $word->Dialogs->Item(228); // returns wdDialogToolsWordCount dialog object
$temp->Execute();   //updates the word count
$numwords = $temp->Words(); //gets the words out of it

echo 'Word count = '.$numwords;

$word->Quit();
//unlink("uploads/".$file);
        }

    }



?>
```

and it gives me the count on local. But on server it gives the error. Please help me what would i do?

Comment: You don't `include` the COM class; it's either compiled in to PHP or it isn't; so is the COM extension `enabled` on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that on your server this component ("word.application") is existed and included into your php document?

Comment: i don't know exactly what the word.application do. can you please explain?

Comment: word.applecation provide you several methods, which allow you to work with Microsoft Word documents via php. Look additional information here http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

Comment: On that link they says thatIf you are seeing this in your error log:

Fatal error:  Class 'COM' not found 

You require this in php.ini:

PHP_COM_DOTNET
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

i added this in php.ini but still error can you please tell where should i upload my php.ini file after changing in it?

Comment: when you make some changes in php.ini you have to restart apache, also check if you have this very extension